# SOLR: Is there any way we can convert Roman numerals to Arabic Numerals

Tags: solr

I am using SOLR for our product search and lot of our products actually have roman numerals instead of arabic numerals.

So both my index content as well as my search string could consist of Roman Numerals.

Google does a good job of this conversion and I was wondering on how to do this in SOLR.
Do I need to write a special filter ?

Comment: do u find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess for a few simple conversions you can use [synonyms](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory)

But for a proper solution you would have to write your own analyzer. And if you want you can [contribute](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute) this to Solr:)

Comment: Looks like someone started working on an English Number Filter to accomplish very thing this back in 2008, but it was never completed. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-690 This might be a good starting point if you decide to go that route.

Comment: I am pretty newbe to SOLR. Not very clear on how filters work ? Any links to suggest how these are done.